# Why are javascript callbacks passed as arguments?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to understand callbacks for the first time. In all the examples I have seen, callbacks are always passed as arguments. Here's a common example:

```
let result = 0;

function add(num1, num2, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        result = num1 + num2;
        callback();
    }, 2000);
}

function logResult() {
    console.log(result);
}

add(4, 5, logResult); // here's the callback passed as argument
```

The same result can be obtained with following code. And it doesn't need callback to be passed as an argument.

```
let result = 0;

function add(num1, num2) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        result = num1 + num2;
        logResult();
    }, 2000);
}

function logResult() {
    console.log(result);
}

add(4, 5);
```

Is it just for readability and understanding code better that they are passed as arguments ? Or is there something that I'm missing? Please can somebody enlighten me ?

Comment: What would happen if `add` was placed in a separate module/file?

Comment: Also your function becomes far less re-usable if you have to declare your callback along with the initial function.

Comment: you realize you are passing a callback to `setTimeout` ?

Comment: It's no different from any other function argument. You could hardcode it to a particular value - and that would work if you wanted that value, and wouldn't work if you wanted a different value in its place. It's the same with callbacks-as-arguments, you can say call `setTimeout`, or add an event listener, and use different functions each time.

Comment: In your example, you know, but usually you don't know how the user might handle the result, you may want to just log, or you may want to manipulate before logging, or validate or...

Comment: Thank you all. I've understood that the main reason is code reusability. And of course the function may not be accessible always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a callback at all in your example, you could just do:

```
function add(num1, num2) {
  setTimeout(() => { // thats a callback too, just saying ...
    const result = num1 + num2; // don't leak variables, declare them!
    console.log(result);
  }, 2000);
}
```

However programming is all about creating *reusable* codes, that can then be composed into more complex programs. Therefore you don't want to limit the usage of `add` to logging the result, instead you can achieve various tasks with it if you accept a callback:

```
 add(1, 2, (result) => {
   add(result, 5, (result2) => {
    alert(result2);
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. Very clearly. I need to learn to generalize things.

Comment: Can you please explain me a bit about that 'dont leak variables, declare them'. What  does it mean? How does it leak ?

Comment: @sushant when you see the `result` getting logged, type `result` into your console ... and you will see that you can access that variable from anywhere as it is actually declared globally.

Comment: Type result into console ? You mean `console.log(num1+num2)` ?

Comment: @ssushant no, just `console.log(result)`

Comment: Yup,  got it now. It can be accessed from anywhere because it's global. So, you gotta declare it locally so that it doesn't leak. Thank you for the lesson.

Comment: Glad to share some knowledge :)

Comment: More to the point, if you have a million LOC program with 500 developers. You will have unexpected results if any one of them uses a variable name called "result". Or even yourself, if you forget you can't use that variable name.

Answer (score 3):

> it doesn't need callback to be passed as an argument.

Yes it does…

> ```
> setTimeout(() => {
> ```

One callback, defined with an arrow function, passed to `setTimeout`.

(I know you mean the function `callback`, but this is still a callback and demonstrates my point)

---

Since `setTimeout` isn't a function you defined, the only way to define a function in a scope it could reach would be to make it a global.

Then if you wanted to have two setTimeout instances running at the same time, you would assign the first callback to the first global and then the second callback … well … you'd be stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Callbacks are a mechanism to decouple code.
For example, assuming `add` part of an API, with the first code, I can write:

```
add(4, 5, console.log);
add(4, 5, alert);
add(4, 5, writeOnTheFileSystemIfNodeJS);
add(4, 5, addToTheDOM);

// etc.
```

That would be impossible to do with your second code: it's too coupled, so I would need different version of the `add` function to do all of the four above: `addConsole`, `addAlert`, etc. Not only: with callback you provide a mechanism to deal with logic that you couldn't anticipate. Maybe the developer want to add the result on a canvas element, and you didn't provide a `addCanvas` thingy. But with the callback, it's possible implemented even if it wasn't design in principle for that purpose.

Notice, however, that nowadays for such kind of operations – that happen *once* – you would likely use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), since they work really well with [await / async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) where for things that can be happens multiple times you will probably want to use *events* (such `addEventListener`), or streams – in a close feature, you would use async queue, thanks to the [async iterators, and `for await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of).

Comment: even in promises, `resolve` and `reject` are callbacks

Comment: Yes, for exactly the same reason: decoupling. But you're not writing yourself the logic of `resolve` and `reject`, you just invoke it.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you for your answer. Yes, I've heard of promises and async/await . And seems like I need to get to them now, since I've finally understood callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a word to the wise:  Callbacks are considered bad practice.  We now have better ways of handling this sort of thing.  As part of the language specification we have `Promise`s.  As far as external libraries go, we also have `Observable`s.
Before it was part of the spec, a `Promise` was built *using* callbacks, but offered you a more readable way of dealing with them, specifically in regards to callback chains.

Very specifically because usually callbacks are used in library code, not your main code, so the library developers are adding in a way for you to add custom functionality to their behavior.  As far as using callbacks in your own code...  depending on the current state of your application and what the caller of the function is, you might desire different callbacks.  Bottom line is that `separation of concerns` is an important concept you need to get familiar with.

For example,

```
function showModal(whichModal) {
  someLibrary.modal(whichModal).show();
  switch (whichModal) {
    case 'createUser':
      someUserLogic();
      break;
    case 'createProject':
      someProjectLogic();
      break;
  }
}

function createUser() {
  showModal('createUser');
}

function createProject() {
  showModal('createProject');
}
```

vs

```
function showModal(whichModal, postShowCallback) {
  someLibrary.modal(whichModal).show();
  postShowCallback();
}

function createUser() {
  showModal('createUser', someUserLogic);
}

function createProject() {
  showModal('createProject', someProjectLogic);
}
```

You can see how quickly the first example would get out of hand, and how elegantly the second solves this problem

Comment: "callbacks are considered bad practice" ... um ... thats quite vague. I'd rather say that there are some scenarios were callbacks get chaotic, and thats where Promises get useful.

Comment: I did hear about promises that were introduced with ES6 but I had to understand callbacks first before moving to promises. Thank you for the example, it made me more clear.

Comment: @JonasWilms  start a google search for "callbacks are considered " and see that the first and only autofill is "harmful" and read a few of the articles linked :-)  I especially like the general consensus that "callbacks are this generation's GOTO statement".  Bottom line, is, as soon as you start using callbacks, you start needing to *chain* callbacks, and then you end up with a giant chaotic mess (as you said).  It is far better to just use Promises *to begin with*.  They are a far more elegant and readable way to achieve the same exact result

Answer (score 0):

One reason callbacks are passed in as arguments is to avoid scoping issues. The `logResult` function in your example may not be defined everywhere you invoke `add`. Also, `logResult` could be mutated. Consider the following:

```js
let result = 0;

function add(num1, num2) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        result = num1 + num2;
        logResult();
    }, 2000);
}

function logResult() {
    console.log(result);
}

add(4, 5);

function logResult() {
    console.log(2);
}
```

In the above snippet, the `logResult` function was [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) and the original version was overwritten. Notice that this happened despite the fact that `add(4, 5)` was invoked before the second `logResult` declaration.

This and other scoping issues can be avoided by accepting a callback argument instead.

```js
function add(a, b, callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        callback(a + b);
    }, 2000);
}

add(4, 5, (result) => setTimeout(() => console.log(result), 2000));
```